# Should JComboBox and JButton Be Added to JTable in the CellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

After reading up on how to add various components to a JTable it is not clear if it should be done external to a custom tablecellrenderer. I have my JTable set up the way I need but now I want to start adding my components to various columns. Here is my skeleton TableCellRenderer:

```
public class TimelineCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table_, Object value_, boolean isSelected_, boolean hasFocus_, int row_,int column_) {

    JTextField editor=new JTextField();
    String str="";
    if (value_!=null) {
        str=value_.toString();
    }
    switch (column_) {
        case 0:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 8:
            editor.setText(str);
            break;
        case 1:
            editor.setText(Double.toString((Double) value_));
            break;
        case 2:
            editor.setText("Meat combobox");
            break;
        case 5:
            editor.setText("Probe combobox");
            break;
        case 6:
            editor.setText("Event combobox");
            break;
        case 7:
            editor.setText("Pit combobox");
            break;
        case 9:
            editor.setText("Add button");
            break;
        case 10:
            editor.setText("del button");
            break;
    }
    Font f=editor.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, (float) 14);
    editor.setFont(f);
    return(editor);
}

}
```

I understand how to create a JComboBox but all the examples show it being added to the table directly. I cannot find anything where it is added via the renderer. I need to customize the various columns so the renderer is necessary but I don't understand if the JComboBox and its editor should be added in the renderer or exactly how. TIA.

Comment: I don't know of any situation where you'd want the renderer to be a combo box, the *editor* yes, but the renderer should just display the value from the model, and not a component.

Comment: Thanks. So what would the renderer return for the editor?

Comment: ?? The renderer and the editor are two separate and unrelated objects. The renderer should have nothing to do with the editor and shouldn't be involved in returning things "for the editor". Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your intent -- do you have a similar question here that you're using for reference? Can you post a valid [mcve] program for us to work with?

Comment: Sorry. My understanding is that the renderer method must return a component which is usually a JTextField. Does the renderer in this case return the JComboBox for that specific column or a JTextField with nothing in it or a null?

Comment: Please reread the tutorial since your understanding is off, and you appear to be confusing renderer with editor.  A default render usually return to JLabel.  For many if not most applications were a JTable uses a combo box editor, the editor component returns a JComboBox, but the renderer is unchanged. The renderer needs to display the **state of the model**, not how you edit the model's data.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now.